# Why is m4 -D option not doing a substitution

Tags: linux, m4

How does `-DQUOTE=yes` work in the code below?

I expected the second line to be `ifelse(yes,yes,Learn Linux today!)`

The other parts make sense to me.

From [Linux Pocket Guide - by Daniel J. Barrett](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/linux-pocket-guide/9780596806347/)

```
$ cat myfile 
My name is NAME and I am AGE years old.
ifelse(QUOTE,yes,Learn Linux today!)


$ m4 -DNAME=Sandy -DAGE=25 -DQUOTE=yes myfile
My name is Sandy and I am 25 years old.
Learn Linux today!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `m4` processor recognizes the names of a number of built-in processing macros when they occur in the input, and `ifelse` is one of these.

It is common to use `m4` with its `-P` option to avoid accidental processing of these instructions.  Using `-P` requires you to prepend the string `m4_` to all built-in instruction names that you want to actually process, e.g. `m4_define`, `m4_ifelse`, `m4_dnl`, etc.

This avoids most accidental executions of macro instructions in the input as no instruction that isn't prepended with `m4_` would be treated as text.

```bsh
$ cat file
My name is NAME and I am AGE years old.
ifelse(QUOTE,yes,Learn Linux today!)
```

```bsh
$ m4 -P -DNAME=Sandy -DAGE=25 -DQUOTE=yes file
My name is Sandy and I am 25 years old.
ifelse(yes,yes,Learn Linux today!)
```

Without `-P`, `ifelse` is processed as the `m4` multi-branch `if`-`then`-`else` instruction.  This instruction is [documented here](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/manual/html_node/Ifelse.html).  In short, if the first two arguments are equal, the whole instruction is replaced by the third argument, which is what you are seeing when you run your initial command: The 1st `yes` (expanded from the value of `QUOTE`) is equal to the 2nd `yes`, so `Learn Linux today!` is expanded.  If you define `QUOTE` as another string, the `ifelse` instruction would be replaced by the 4th argument, but sine there isn't any 4th argument in your document, it would be replaced by nothing (i.e. removed).